# template twig not found

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, render

I have a problem with a render function in my controller.

I have:

- a bundle, named `CoreBundle`
- a controller named `DefaultController`
- in which I have an action named `loginAction`
- in which I am trying to render a template twig with this line

`return $this->render('FooCoreBundle::Default:layout.html.twig', array());`

I am always having the same not found error for the template. I have tried with an other template twig it is the same problem. In my views folder I have a `Accueil` folder in which i have put the `login.html.twig` template I want to render.

I tried to replace it directly in views folder but no changes. Sorry for my english hope you can help. Thank You.

Comment: Use `FooCoreBundle:Accueil:login.html.twig'. The controller has no relevance in the twig template name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A worth-while reading piece of info from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle):

> Symfony uses a **bundle:directory:filename** string syntax for
>   templates that live inside a bundle. This allows for several types of
>   templates, each which lives in a specific location.

Supposing:

- *FooCoreBundle* is your bundle -> `src/Foo/CoreBundle`
- *Default* is the template directory -> `src/Foo/CoreBundle/Resources/views/Default`
- *layout.html.twig* is your file -> `src/Foo/CoreBundle/Resources/views/Default/layout.html.twig`

Then the route you should use would be `'FooCoreBundle:Default:layout.html.twig'` without the `::` you're using in `'FooCoreBundle::Default:layout.html.twig'`

The `::` refers to a base template specific to the bundle. If you used `FooCoreBundle::layout.html.twig` then your template should live at `Resources/views/layout.html.twig` inside `FooCoreBundle`.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Thank u for your answers, i have tried : bundle:directory:filename =>  return $this->render('NeobeCoreBundle:Accueil:login.html.twig', array()); but i have this error  : "NeobeAccueilBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. It conisders Accueil as a bundle and not as folder. As mulder says, the truth is somewhere else.

Comment: Please, post the route to your template, f.i `src/Foo/CoreBundle/Resources/views/Default/layout.html.twig` and I'll try to provide and explanation and a correct symfony path

Comment: Thank you everybody, the mistake was in the login.html.twig  file when i tried to insert css files i wrote  '@NeobeAccueilBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' that explain the error "NeobeAccueilBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. it was true accueilBundle does not exist anymore copy and paste mistake. Sorry and thank u for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 return $this->render('NeobeCoreBundle:Default:Accueil:layout.html.twig', array());
```

No double colon, add the `Accueil` subfolder

Comment: Thank u for your answer but it still tells me : 
Unable to find template "FooCoreBundle:Default:Accueil:login.html.twig".

Comment: Please read carefully error messages: the name of the bundle is different.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an answer, but it could be handy for those who arrives here with symfony 4.

In documentation authors says do not organize your business logic into bundles.

> In modern Symfony applications, it's no longer recommended to organize your business logic using bundles.

Of course you can, just not recommended. See [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-deprecated-the-bundle-notation).